# as3 save swf stage to desktop - only works in IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I followed a tip here on saving the stage as a png ([is there a way for flash AS3 to take a snapshot of a frame then save it as jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404723/is-there-a-way-for-flash-as3-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-frame-then-save-it-as-jpeg) but using PNGEncoder instead). It works when run in Flash - I get a dialog box asking for where to save the file. But in a browser it just stalls out without showing the dialog box - and not running the code after that command. Are there security issues with using such code in a browser? Or is there something else going on here.

Comment: There are security issues with saving images - it has to be in response to a user action (ie mouse or keyboard event) - but if its working in Flash IDE that shouldnt be the issue. Post your code or explain error in more detail (eg screenshot, error message)

Comment: I just got a tip from a co-worker that saved me. Essentially it's what you noted: the save dialog box was triggered by a function called from the onComplete param of a Tweenlite command. Once I took out the Tweenlite command and called the function's code directly it worked as expected! Whew!!

Comment: ok. please vote up my comment and mark question as answered. cheers

Comment: Ummmm.... I don't see buttons for that. Does there need to be an answer versus a comment to do that?

Comment: maybe there needs to be an answer to actually mark it as answered...so i added one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are security issues with saving images - it has to be in response to a user action (ie mouse or keyboard event)